# How to configure nginx with multiple server

Tags: nginx

Im new with nginx as well as load balancing, rediction etc. I have 2 tornado web servers running on port 8000 and 8001 and 2 geoserver instance running on tomcat7 servelet with ports 8080 and 8081. Can someone teach me in such a way that nginx could listen to port 80 and base_url/tornado will be redirected to the tornado servers and base_url/geoserver will be redirected to the tomcat7 servelet.

Thanks to those who would help me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be a good lead for you towards the solution:

```
upstream tornado {
  server 127.0.0.1:8000;
  server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}

upstream geoserver{
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
  server 127.0.0.1:8081;
}
server {
  server_name _;
  listen 80;
  location = /tornado {
    proxy_pass http://tornado;
  }

  location = /geoserver {
    proxy_pass http://geoserver;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!